Convert Unix time to local time python
I have a string representing a unix timestamp (i.e. "1715812515") in Python, and I'd like to convert it to a readable date

It looks like the online system recognises your location (Bangalore) as being in India, and displays the time correctly. But you have not explained anything about  this online system that you used, so we cannot make any useful suggestions.

Need to convert the string UTC to any date time . I just took the example of the above online conversion.

from datetime import datetime
ts = int('1715812515')
if you encounter a "year is out of range" error the timestamp
may be in milliseconds, try ts /= 1000 in that case
print(datetime.utcfromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))

@OldBoy Try my below answer

OK, that tells me it is 2024-05-15 22:35:15. So what is wrong with that? BTW, please do not post updates to your question as answers, edit your actual question and update it there.

from datetime import datetime 
ts = int('1715812515') 

# if you encounter a "year is out of range" error the timestamp
# may be in milliseconds, try `ts /= 1000` in that case

print(datetime.utcfromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))


Here is how you are going to get your datetime local timezone in Python. You can now use the time object to further manipulate what you want. The timestamp utc parameter must be passed as a number in the function as we did for it to work.
The comment I added is to help you understand what each line of code does.
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil import tz

# install dateutil library using pip in your machine using this -> pip install python-dateutil

def convert_utc_to_local_tz(local_timestamp):

    """ convert the utc timestam to local time zone """

    # Convert UTC timestamp to UTC datetime
    utc_datetime = datetime.fromtimestamp(local_timestamp)
    #utc_datetime = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(local_timestamp)

    # specify your local timezone (e.g., "America/New_York")
    local_tz = tz.gettz("America/New_York")

    # convert to local time
    local_datetime = utc_datetime.replace(tzinfo=tz.UTC).astimezone(local_tz)

    # finally return the local date time as a time object
    return local_datetime.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

# pass the local timestamp representation you want as an argument, and you 
# are good to go.
print(convert_utc_to_local_tz(1715812515)) # your answer -> 2024-05-15 19:35:15

Goodluck!

Did you create this answer with ChatGPT?
